# SQL Server db user mapped to windows login not in SQL Server logins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, logins

I am on a SQL Server 2008 where I login with DOMAIN\USER_A

On my database I can see this login is mapped to the user dbo of that database.
What I don't understand is that DOMAIN\USER_A is nowhere to be found in the SQL Servers Security Logins.

CURRENT_USER reports dbo
SYSTEM_USER reports DOMAIN\USER_A as do SUSER_NAME

I can't find DOMAIN\USER_A in the sys.syslogins? What is going on? Can a database user have its own login circumventing the SQL Server?

Comment: Where do you see they are "mapped to" `dbo`?

Comment: May it is an orphaned user: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way a login has rights to a server is if those rights have been granted.  The question is likely:  How did these rights get granted?

If DOMAIN\USER_A is a member of some Windows group, then through the rights granted to the group the DOMAIN\USER_A login exists in the server.  This is true even if there is no individual entry in sys.database_principals or sys.server_principals for that login.

You can look for the permission paths used by a login as follows:

```
EXEC xp_logininfo 'DOMAIN\USER_A', 'all'
```

You might find several permission paths for a login.

Comment: I dont have the rights to execute the that stored procedure :(

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct since it pointed me in the right direction and figured out the problem. I will have to play around a little on my company network i think to fully understand it.

Comment: Thank you i understand it now :) gpresult /R shows me my group memberships and i was in a group mapped to a SQL login.

Answer (score 4):

Please stop looking at `syslogins`. This is a deprecated system table that is now a backward compatibility view and is only there for that purpose (to prevent breaking old code).

The user is `dbo` probably because they created the database.

You should be able to find the login the user is associated with using:

```
SELECT login_name = sp.name, user_name = dp.name
  FROM that_database.sys.database_principals AS dp
  INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp
  ON dp.[sid] = sp.[sid];
```

Now, it may be that the user doesn't have its own login, and has been granted access to the instance via a Windows group.

Comment: Yields no result as the login do not exist on the SQL Server.

Comment: @Jeppe probably because, as I said in the next sentence, the login got in via a Windows group.